# How to speedup Soft Body simulations in Blender?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

Is there a way to speedup Soft Body simulation in blender like in cinema 4d: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CykigKQwadU

I have a high-poly object and I can not animate it with soft body dynamics.

Thanks!